# Rotating empty deforms my mesh (Peter France's tutorial)

Tags: mesh

Blender version: 2.92

I'm watching Peter France's tutorial about creating a Spider-Man animation. He creates an empty, parents it to SM keeping transform and in "constraints" adds "follow path" and chooses a path. I do the same and everything works fine until i'm trying to rotate an empty to rotate an actual model. Idk why but it deforms my mesh. Before creating an empty Peter France says that "without it your mesh will be deformed if you try to rotate it" but it deforms anyway. I've tried adding a "follow path" constrait directly to my model but it still deforms. I was experimenting with "influence" but it just moves my model away and it stops following the path.
[image: No rotaion]
This is how it look like before i'm trying to rotate the empty
[image: With rotation]
And this is the result of rotating it

I've rewatched the tutorial a few times but I haven't noticed any differences. I repeat same actions he does.
This is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0hWrpAG6Sg
My problem begins at 9:13. He rotates an empty an it works fine.

And sry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.
You can use the "Locked Track" constraint in the Spiderman body + Rig. And add a target as Spiderman body. It worked for me. Do let me know if this works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The curve itself had a problem. If you select the curve and hit *Object > Apply > Rotation & Scale*, everything would go same as tutorial video.